# possible alternative to psycopg2.connect

Tags: sql, django, database, postgresql

I have made a chatting app in django (with log in and sign up) , and I have configured the database (created tables through the pgadmin4 gui)
my sign-up function is something like this :

```
@csrf_exempt
def signUp(request):
    
    IP = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    jned = json.loads(request.body)
    email = jned['email']
    password = jned['password']
    user_id = tokenGen()
    user_token = tokenGen()
    now = int(time.time())
    create_user =  f'''insert into auth_user(idx,email,passwordx,ip,utime,tokenx) 
                                    values ('{user_id}','{email}','{password}','{IP}','{now}','{user_token}')'''
    try: 
        connection = psycopg2.connect(user="postgres",
                                password="0000",
                                host="127.0.0.1",
                                port="5432",
                                database="project1")
    except:
        print('error in connection ')
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor2 = connection.cursor()
    cursor2.execute(f"SELECT * FROM auth_user WHERE email = '{email}'")
    if cursor2.rowcount >0 :
        print('email already exists')
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'status':'email already exists' , 'done':False}))
    else:
    values('{jned['email']}','{ip}','{hashit(jned['password'])}','{token}',{int(time.time())})")
    cursor.execute(create_user)
    connection.commit()
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'status':'never used this website huh?' , 'done':True, 'token':user_token}))
```

everything works perfectly fine.
but I think that I am connecting to the database in a wrong way, all the tutorials on youtube setup the database in settings.py , taking a completely different path (they use models and django.db).
so , the question is : can I push this to production or should I write all the database models even though I don't need them?

Comment: have you considered if having the database credentials in prod is okay? Also, what if you need to change the host/port in production? Also, using raw text in queries might expose your underlying database to certain SQL attacks.

Comment: 1) Do yourself a favor an read the [Parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/) for how deal with parameters safely. Hint `f` strings are not it. 2) You can use `settings.py` and then run direct queries. See [Raw queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/sql/) and the section headed as *Executing custom SQL directly*. I do this on a regular basis.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver 
thanks for the suggestion, I read the docs and found out that I should never use fstrings, not even at gunpoint.
so here is what I will do now, let me know if I should do it differently 
1 - store the database info as env variables
2 - change the query create_user (and all others) to this format
`create_user =  '''insert into auth_user(idx,email,passwordx,ip,utime,tokenx) 
                                    values(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,)''', (user_id,email,password,IP,now,user_token)`

then I should be good to go, right?

Comment: You did not actually read the Django link I posted. If you had you would know you would set up the database in `settings.py` and then use `from django.db import connection` to get the connection from there.

Comment: Please fix the english grammar/orthography in your text. Also, question title is not indicative of your actual question, please fix it as well.

Comment: https://github.com/sfu-db/connector-x